# Sum of (func tree) elements

Tags: haskell, recursion, tree

I'm struggling in finding a solution to my last assignment. I have to implement a function `sumSucc` that takes an `IntTree` and returns the sum of the elements of the tree obtained from `succTree`.

`succTree` basically returns the successor of a given tree and is defined as follows:

```
succTree :: IntTree -> IntTree
succTree t = tmap (+1) t
```

I know I could easily solve this by doing the following:

```
sumSucc :: IntTree -> Int
sumSucc (Leaf x) = x+1
sumSucc (Branch (x, xl, xr)) = (x+1) + sumSucc xl + sumSucc xr
```

But I have to use the function `succTree` inside of `sumSucc`. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement another function `sumTree`, and then `sumSucc` is equivalent to:

```
sumSucc :: IntTree -> Int
sumSucc x = sumTree (succTree x)

sumTree :: IntTree -> Int
sumTree (Leaf x) = …
sumTree (Branch (x, xl, xr)) = …
```

here you thus should implement the `…` parts of `sumTree`. I leave this as an exercise.

The `sumSucc` can be implemented without a parameter, and make use of [**`(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:.):

```
sumSucc :: IntTree -> Int
sumSucc = sumTree . succTree
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I actually already thought about auxiliary functions/variable in order to solve it. But I was wondering if there was a way that includes everything inside sumSucc.

Comment: @MatteoPinna: you can define `sumSucc` in a `where` clause, such that it is only available in the `sumTree` function.